# Ubuntu 18.04 Intel Wireless 3165 adapter not found

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 18.04

New install of Ubuntu 18.04 on a Geo Flex 1M, this doesn't have an ethernet port. The wifi adapter 'Intel Corporation Wireless 3165' doesn't show up (this seems to crop up in a few posts).

I've done a fair amount of looking around on this site already so have hopefully provided some information that is relevant (hopefully).

It came with Windows and the wifi adapter was working on that before promptly converted it to Linux.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advanced.

Have also tried re-downloading the drivers and copying them to /lib/firmware - still didn't resolve the issue
https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi

```
$ uname -a
Linux garwooduk-linux 4.18.0-15-generic #16~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Feb 7 14:06:04 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
--------
$ dmesg | grep iwl
<no output>
--------
$ lspci | egrep -i --colour 'network|ethernet'
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 (rev 79)

--------
$ dmesg | grep -i 3165
[    0.522591] pci 0000:01:00.0: [8086:3165] type 00 class 0x028000
[    6.080211] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 3165, REV=0xFFFFFFFF

--------
$ dmesg | grep -i error
<no output>
--------
$ dmesg | grep -i sdio
<no output>
--------
$ modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl
<no output>
--------
$ lspci -nnk | grep 8086
<OMMITED>
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 [8086:3165] (rev 79)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 [8086:8110]

--------
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

--------
$ lshw -C network
  *-network
       description: Network controller
       product: Wireless 3165
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 79
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
       resources: irq:22 memory:a1100000-a1101fff
--------
$ lspci -knn
<no output>
--------
$ rfkill list all
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

```
grep -i iwlwifi /var/log/syslog*
May 26 15:42:07 garwooduk-linux kernel: [    6.328856] RIP: 0010:iwl_trans_pcie_grab_nic_access+0x182/0x210 [iwlwifi]
May 26 15:42:07 garwooduk-linux kernel: [    6.328902]  iwl_write_prph+0x3d/0x90 [iwlwifi]
May 26 15:42:07 garwooduk-linux kernel: [    6.328910]  iwl_pcie_apm_init+0x1db/0x240 [iwlwifi]
May 26 15:42:07 garwooduk-linux kernel: [    6.328918]  iwl_trans_pcie_start_hw+0x4e/0x1c0 [iwlwifi]
May 26 15:42:07 garwooduk-linux kernel: [    6.328943]  _iwl_op_mode_start.isra.10+0x4c/0xa0 [iwlwifi]
May 26 15:42:07 garwooduk-linux kernel: [    6.328950]  iwl_opmode_register+0x75/0xe0 [iwlwifi]
May 26 15:42:07 garwooduk-linux kernel: [    6.329032] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: iwlwifi transaction failed, dumping registers
May 26 15:42:07 garwooduk-linux kernel: [    6.329035] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: iwlwifi device config registers:
May 26 15:42:07 garwooduk-linux kernel: [    6.329052] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 00000000: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
May 26 15:42:07 garwooduk-linux kernel: [    6.329055] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 00000020: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
May 26 15:42:07 garwooduk-linux kernel: [    6.329056] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: iwlwifi device memory mapped registers:
May 26 15:42:07 garwooduk-linux kernel: [    6.329067] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 00000000: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
May 26 15:42:07 garwooduk-linux kernel: [    6.329069] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 00000020: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
May 26 15:42:07 garwooduk-linux kernel: [    6.329319] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: iwlwifi parent port (0000:00:13.0) config registers:
May 26 15:42:07 garwooduk-linux kernel: [    6.329333] iwlwifi 0000:00:13.0: 00000000: 31d88086 00100407 060400f3 00810010 00000000 00000000 00010100 200000f0
May 26 15:42:07 garwooduk-linux kernel: [    6.329335] iwlwifi 0000:00:13.0: 00000020: a110a110 0001fff1 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000040 00000000 0010010a
May 26 15:42:07 garwooduk-linux kernel: [    7.073396] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Could not load the [0] uCode section
May 26 15:42:07 garwooduk-linux kernel: [    7.073407] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to start INIT ucode: -5
May 26 15:42:07 garwooduk-linux kernel: [    8.848023] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
May 26 16:13:22 garwooduk-linux kernel: [    6.172731] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Refused to change power state, currently in D3
May 26 16:13:22 garwooduk-linux kernel: [    6.172847] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: pci_enable_msi failed - -22
May 26 16:13:22 garwooduk-linux kernel: [    6.205045] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: loaded firmware version 29.1044073957.0 op_mode iwlmvm
May 26 16:13:22 garwooduk-linux kernel: [    6.294736] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 3165, REV=0xFFFFFFFF
May 26 16:13:22 garwooduk-linux kernel: [    6.316933] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 357 at /build/linux-hwe-9KJ07q/linux-hwe-4.18.0/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/pcie/trans.c:2008 iwl_trans_pcie_grab_nic_access+0x182/0x210 [iwlwifi]
May 26 16:13:22 garwooduk-linux kernel: [    6.316935] Modules linked in: iwlmvm(+) snd_soc_acpi snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_soc_core mac80211 snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic uvcvideo snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine videobuf2_vmalloc snd_usb_audio videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 snd_usbmidi_lib videobuf2_common rtsx_usb_ms videodev snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec memstick media iwlwifi btusb snd_hda_core btrtl btbcm btintel snd_hwdep bluetooth snd_pcm idma64 virt_dma snd_seq_midi cfg80211 intel_lpss_pci(+) intel_lpss ecdh_generic snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq goodix snd_seq_device snd_timer mac_hid snd mei_me intel_hid mei soundcore processor_thermal_device int3400_thermal int3403_thermal intel_soc_dts_iosf sparse_keymap int340x_thermal_zone acpi_thermal_rel sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4
May 26 16:13:22 garwooduk-linux kernel: [    6.316997] RIP: 0010:iwl_trans_pcie_grab_nic_access+0x182/0x210 [iwlwifi]
```

Comment: Can you please confirm which release of Ubuntu, you say a new 18.10 install, but refer to 18.04 in the heading & tag.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. It is 18.04